# How can I check if page is my admin setting page?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to enqueue script and style for my custom setting page. I want enqueue my script only if I am on my settings page.

I have created custom setting page with the snippet

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'supernut_shipping_admin_menu' );

function supernut_shipping_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( __('Способы доставки'), 'Способы доставки', 'manage_options',
        'supernut/shipping-methods', 'supernut_shipping_admin_page',
        'dashicons-tickets', 6  );
}
```

I want to achive this

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'supernut_enqueue_admin_scripts_and_styles');
function supernut_enqueue_admin_scripts_and_styles() {
    if  (is_admin('supernut/shipping-methods')) {
        // Enqueue my script and styles
    } 
}
```

How can I check current page is my custom setting page in admin?
`if  (is_admin('supernut/shipping-methods'))` - doesn`t work.

Comment: is_admin doesn't have any parameters to pass to the function.

Comment: I know, it is for example. I want to achive something like this but I don`t know which template tag to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this snippet [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7278/how-can-you-check-if-you-are-in-a-particular-page-in-the-wp-admin-section-for-e):

The way to do this is to use the 'admin_enqueue_scripts' hook to en-queue the files you need. This hook will get passed a `$hook_suffix` that relates to the current page that is loaded:

```
function my_admin_enqueue($hook_suffix) {
    if($hook_suffix == 'appearance_page_theme-options') {
        wp_enqueue_script('my-theme-settings', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme-settings.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_style('my-theme-settings', get_template_directory_uri() . '/styles/theme-settings.css');
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var template_directory = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>';
        //]]>
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue');
```

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to do it and it's a bit simpler as we don't need to know the `$hook_suffix` name. The relevant actions are all [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-admin/admin-header.php#L68). Noting that when we use double quotes PHP will render the variable inside them: `"admin_print_styles-$hook_suffix"`.

```
add_action('admin_menu', function() {
    $hook_suffix = add_menu_page (
        'Test Hook Suffix',
        'HSuffix',
        'manage_options',
        'hook_suffix',
        function(){ echo '<h1>menu</h1>'; },
        'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
        6
    );
    add_action("admin_print_styles-$hook_suffix", 'my_admin_css');
    add_action("admin_print_scripts-$hook_suffix", 'my_admin_js');
});

function my_admin_css(){
    wp_enqueue_style('my-theme-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/test.css');
}
function my_admin_js(){
    wp_enqueue_script('my-theme-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/test.js', array('jquery'));   
}
```

Comment: It is elegant way. Thanks for you help!